# How to defined interface for "this" keyword of function

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have 1 class and 1 function like the bellow

```
class A {
  
  functionA = functionA.bind(this)
  functionB (name : string) {
    return name
  }
}
const functionA = function () {
  const name = this.functionB("functionA")
  
}
```

Typescript cannot detect interface for "this" using in functionA, it say "this" as any
How can I specify interface for "this" in functionA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`this` parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters), you can annotate the type of `this` inside the function:

```
const functionA = function (this: A) {
```